# EXC bad access while selecting twitter account from actionsheet in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsarray, exc-bad-access

I'm now currently fetching the twitter account configured in the device and display in action sheet and when I select a account I get exc bad access error. It crashes in the actionsheet delegate method where I print the twitterArray

```
@interface LogInViewController ()
{
    NSArray *twitterAccountsArray;
    ACAccount *selectedAccount;
}

-(void)getTwitterAccountsForLogin
{

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                            withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

                                if (granted && !error) {
                                    twitterAccountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                                    NSLog(@"Account:%@",twitterAccountsArray);
                                    if(twitterAccountsArray == nil || [twitterAccountsArray count] == 0)
                                    {
                                        showAlert(@"Message", TWITTER_NO_ACCOUNT_ERROR , STRING_CONSTANT_OK, nil);
                                    }
                                    else if ([twitterAccountsArray count] > 1)
                                    {

                                        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(accountListActionSheetDynamics:) withObject:twitterAccountsArray waitUntilDone:YES];

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                      NSLog(@"Only one twitter account so login to that");
                                       }
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    showAlert(@"Message", TWITTER_ACCESS_DENIED, STRING_CONSTANT_OK, nil);
                                }
                            }];


}

- (void)accountListActionSheetDynamics:(NSArray *) accounts {
    UIActionSheet *accountsSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Choose a Twitter Account"
                                    delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [accountsSheet setDelegate:self];

    for(int i=0;i<accounts.count;i++)
    {
        [accountsSheet addButtonWithTitle:[[accounts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"username"]];
    }
    accountsSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [accountsSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    [accountsSheet showFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
       NSLog(@"Account:%@",twitterAccountsArray);

}

-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
       //Crashes here with exc bad access while printing log
        NSLog(@"Account:%@",twitterAccountsArray);

  for(int i=0;i<twitterAccountsArray.count;i++)

        if([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] caseInsensitiveCompare:    [[twitterAccountsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"username"]]==NSOrderedSame)
        {
            selectedAccount = [twitterAccountsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
}
```

The `NSLog(@"Account:%@",twitterAccountsArray);` prints fine in the action sheet method and the initial twitter method but crashes in the action sheet delegate method. Any ideas. This happens only in iOS5 works fine for iOS6 and above

Comment: Maybe that the array is getting auto released, If your project has ARC enabled, you can try putting `__strong` in front of `NSArray *twitterAccountsArray;`.

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: @Zen i did tried that but that didnt help, i think it has value as when it crashes and when i hover my mouse over twitterAccountsArray it shows 2 objects, i dont understand why the log is crashing if it contains data, it printed just fine before.

Comment: Then please post the error trace.

Comment: Did u meant the crash log?

Comment: [__NSCFType parentAccountForAccount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4f4650
* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType parentAccountForAccount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4f4650' This is the crash log I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by making accountStore and accountType global

```
@interface LogInViewController ()
{
    NSArray *twitterAccountsArray;
    ACAccount *selectedAccount;
    ACAccountStore *accountStore;
    ACAccountType *accountType;
}
```